# MPAndroidChart PieChartRenderer crash when device is in landscape mode

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndroidChart in my application.
I've received a lot of report from my users.
The problem that they faced is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:922)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:901)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:868)
at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.PieChartRenderer.drawData(PieChartRenderer.java:79)
at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart.onDraw(PieChart.java:96)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15423)
...
```

These are the line that cause the crash.

```
 mDrawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) mViewPortHandler.getChartWidth(),
(int) mViewPortHandler.getChartHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The app crash only when my tablet is in landscape mode.

Seem that onSizeChanged in the Chart class isn't called when my device is in landscape mode.
landscape mode -> portrait mode, onSizeChanged called
portrait mode -> landscape mode, onSizeChanged not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The application crash when I try to programatically chance the LayoutParams of the container.

When i use only the parameter specified in the xml layout it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed right that the height the `Bitmap` is initialized with is never checked.

I just published a fix for this, it's in the latest commit: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/commit/bff61718198f839aa819c8769d4f71e755625b94

You can go and check it out or wait until I release the next version.